# Screen goes blank after suspending and never wakes up. Fix?

Tags: 16.04, suspend

I have recently switched from Windows to Linux and have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installed dual booted with Windows 10. Things were working fine until yesterday I found out if the computer is suspended (either by putting the lid down or due to inactivity), it never wakes up. 
I looked into other forums and found no exact solution to the problem.

This could have happened because I installed a lot of .deb files by mistake and now a lot of unmet dependencies are left. A log file as big as 37 GB was made which I had to compress to save space.

I have tried deselecting the lock screen after suspension option and not suspending if screen turns off. It helps if the screen has been off for little time like 5-10 minutes. But in long term screen off situations, the screen never wakes up.

How do I fix this?

P.S. I am new to the Linux world so this kind of basic problem is pretty problematic for me.

Comment: I've just learned that with systemd, we're meant to use this command to suspend: `sudo systemctl suspend` - for the first time ever I was able to resume from suspend successfully! See if it works for you.

Comment: I think we should get rid of the package management issues first to eliminate potential sources for the issue and make things easier down the road. What's the out of `sudo apt-get install -f ubuntu-desktop`?

Answer (score 0):

You know, I had similar problem on a previous version of ubuntu.
That time I've heard that energy management applications were difficult to write, so they did not support suspending on all hardware.
You said you installed lots of broken deb files, you'll probably want to reinstall linux, its not difficult.
But as you were sure it was ok, probably the easyest thing for you to do is re-install ubuntu.
Other quick-fix you could try is to disable ACPI on BIOS and put "never suspend" on energy settings.
You could file a bug if you knew you had a bug for it to get fixed on next ubuntu release, but this is unlikely your case. You probably broke something.

Comment: >> You probably broke something
@Cloacker Looks like this is happening for many people. Even for me. I have installed very few apps. That too via GUI. Still my system does not respond once screen turns off. But when i put `Lock` (autommatic) `On` this doesn't see to happen.